# WordPress image gallery plug-in with editing, filtering and moderation capabilities

Tags: images, image-processing, wordpress, image-editor, plug-in

We are looking for an image gallery plug-in that:

1. Includes basic image editing within the interface (crop, resize)
2. Allows for filtering and sorting by attributes (categories) within gallery
3. Has multi tier moderation: One user tier should be able to upload images, tag and title through a form interface but the images are not immediately posted for public view. A higher tier of user would be able to view the submissions and moderate - approving, editing or disapproving for public view.

Anything out there that does this?